# PHP Re-adds value to MYSQL on page refresh

Tags: php, mysql, variables, refresh

im fairly new to php, but i know my way around, and ive done lots of research on this problem, but still cannot find the right solution to this. Here's my php code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <form action="default.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="hname">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    require("connect.php");
    $con = mysql_connect("mysql10.000webhost.com","$username","$password");
    $pname=$_POST[hname];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO web_members(name) VALUES('$pname')");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM web_members");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "<br />";
    }

    ?>
```

And basically it adds and displays the variable fine, but whenever i refresh the page it repeats the process. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 1):

use code like below

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
$con = mysql_connect("mysql10.000webhost.com","$username","$password");
if(isset($_POST[hname]))
{
   $pname=$_POST[hname];
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO web_members(name) VALUES('$pname')");
   header("location:default.php");
}
else
{
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM web_members");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      echo $row['name'];
      echo "<br />";
   }
}

?>
```

hope it will help you. thanks.

Comment: @user2016831 You are always welcome. I am here for helping everybody if I know the answers of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168) for this. It prevents form resubmissions.